# Html/Css 2 Adjacent containers and reflow

Tags: css, wordpress, html, header

I'm new to HTML/CSS - if I didn't do it, assume I don't know it.

I want these the site-title and site-desc elements on the right of the headerimg; they display this way at certain browser widths of course, with the float option. I want them to remain adjacent despite browser width as much as possible.

Also, I want to have the header container expand to hold them - the main body beneath is a different color, so the image moves down onto that as the browser width narrows.

Here's the relevant stuff from header.php:

```
<hgroup>
   <?php
       // Check to see if the header image has been removed
       $header_image = get_header_image();
       if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) :
   ?>
  <h1 id="site-logo">
       <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
            <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" />
       </a>
  </h1>
      <?php endif; // end check for removed header image ?> 
<div id="headertext"><span> 
    <h1 id="site-title"><span><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></span></h1>
    <h2 id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2></span>
        </div>
            <div id="headerimg">
             <img src="/wp-content/themes/catch-box/images/Puzz_letters.png" align="left" />
        </div>
</hgroup>
```

And here's the style.css:

```
#headertext {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#headerimg {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: you might want to at least give a reference image for us to understand your requirement.

Comment: @xFortyFourx dumb question: you mean a link to something like what I'm looking for?

Comment: Yes, or make a mockup of how you want the layers to be arranged (MS Paint would do), and upload. http://imgur.com is a free img hosting site.

Comment: [IMG]http://i.imgur.com/x80mu8L.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: The "Smaller screens" is what happens now, not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
<hgroup>
<?php
   // Check to see if the header image has been removed
   $header_image = get_header_image();
   if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) :
?>

<div id="site-logo">
   <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
      <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" />
   </a>
</div>

<?php endif; // end check for removed header image ?> 

<div id="headertext">
    <h1 id="site-title">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
    </h1>

    <h2 id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
</div>

<div id="headerimg">
  <img src="/wp-content/themes/catch-box/images/Puzz_letters.png" align="left" />
</div>

<div class="clear"> </div>

</hgroup>

<div class="clear"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
#site-logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

#headertext {
  float: left;
}

#site-title {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both; /* Look up what clear:both does. */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) { /* define your smaller screen styles inside this */
    #site-logo, #headertext {
     float: none;
    }     

}
```

It's not possible with CSS (not in a good way) to change position of your logo to the bottom when in a smaller screen.

Comment: Hmm maybe I wasn't clear enough. I tried applying your solution without much like, excerpt for the @media screen size definitions, which did help.

I ended up creating a wrapper div and using position: absolute on the headerimg (which is what's in there; I don't have a site-logo up). It works on all screens now. Thanks!